# Multiple circular progress bar becoming active on scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, progress-bar

I want four different circular progress bar in my webpage which will be placed on one particular div.Upon scrolling at that div I want all of them to be active at the same time and finishes on the specified percentage. 
Only one is working fine.How can I do this? Here, is the attached code.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
var al = 0;
var start = 4.72;
var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
var diff;

function progressSim() {
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText(al + 'K TOURIST', cw * .5, ch * .5 + 2, cw);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(35, 35, 30, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  /*ctx.arc(200,75,50,0*Math.PI,1.5*Math.PI);*/
  ctx.stroke();
  if (al >= 50) {
    clearTimeout(sim);
    // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
  }
  al++;
}
var sim = setInterval(progressSim, 50);
```

```html
<div id="first_progress">
  <canvas id="my_canvas" width="70" height="70" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="second_progress">
  <canvas id="my_canvas2" width="70" height="70" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed the jQuery tag as you have no jQuery in the code nor do you mention it in the question. If you are after a jQuery solution then you can edit the question add back the jQuery tag and make mention of that fact you are after solution that may/must include  jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seem you only update one canvas. you need to update both canvas using two different contexts. or you could draw the progress bars into the same but bigger canvas.

this example will not help using four. you need to store different angles and progress you know for each bar but it show how to update the two in the example.

hope it works out. ps - use arrays to store the ctx's and values. much easier that way.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
var ctx2 = document.getElementById('my_canvas2').getContext('2d');
var al = 0;
var start = 4.72;
var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
var diff;

function progressSim(ctx, simInx) {
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#09F';
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#09F";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillText(al + 'K TOURIST', cw * .5, ch * .5 + 2, cw);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(35, 35, 30, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  /*ctx.arc(200,75,50,0*Math.PI,1.5*Math.PI);*/
  ctx.stroke();
  if (al >= 50) {
    clearTimeout(simInx == 1 ? sim1 : sim2);
    // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
  }
  al++;
}
var sim1 = setInterval(progressSim, 50, ctx, 1);
var sim2 = setInterval(progressSim, 50, ctx2, 2);
```

```html
<div id="first_progress">
  <canvas id="my_canvas" width="70" height="70" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="second_progress">
  <canvas id="my_canvas2" width="70" height="70" style="border:1px dashed #CCC;"></canvas>
</div>
```